# XAML Binding Failures on ComboBox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have created a ComboBox that adds an item inside XAML, this is so I can have an uneditable ComboBox with an option that will set the binded item null.

[image: ComboBox Clear Screenshot]

The following code works, however Visual Studio is reporting a few XAML binding failures that I don't know how to fix.

```
<ComboBox x:Name="NewNewComboBox"
          SelectedValuePath="CompCategoryId"
          DisplayMemberPath="CategoryName">
    <ComboBox.Resources>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="MyCollection" Source="{Binding Categories}"/>
    </ComboBox.Resources>
    <ComboBox.ItemsSource>
        <CompositeCollection>
            <ComboBoxItem FontStyle="Italic" FontSize="8px" Content="(clear)" />
            <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource MyCollection}}"  />
        </CompositeCollection>
    </ComboBox.ItemsSource>
    <ComboBox.SelectedValue>
        <Binding Path="CompCategoryId"/>
    </ComboBox.SelectedValue>
</ComboBox>
```

[image: XAML Binding Failures Screenshot]

Note: A normal ComboBox (without the *(clear)* item) does not show any failures.

**Edit:** I would like the solution to avoid code specific to the class the ComboBox uses because I want to make this ComboBox as a **UserControl** so it can be reused on different class (which will all have an int *Id* and string *Name*, already defined by the SelectedValuePath and DisplayMemberPath)

I have amended the ComboBoxItem and no longer receive XAML Binding Failures.  But I cannot edit the FontStyle of it (and I have no clue how to implement this as a re-usable UserControl)

```
<ComboBox x:Name="NewNewComboBox"
          SelectedValuePath="CompCategoryId"
          DisplayMemberPath="CategoryName"
          SelectionChanged="NewNewComboBox_SelectionChanged">
    <ComboBox.Resources>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="MyCollection" Source="{Binding Categories}"/>
    </ComboBox.Resources>
    <ComboBox.ItemsSource>
        <CompositeCollection>
            <m:CompCategory CategoryName="(clear)" CompCategoryId="0"/>
            <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource MyCollection}}"  />
        </CompositeCollection>
    </ComboBox.ItemsSource>
    <ComboBox.SelectedValue>
        <Binding Path="CompCategoryId"/>
    </ComboBox.SelectedValue>
</ComboBox>

private void NewNewComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (NewNewComboBox.SelectedIndex == 0) NewNewComboBox.SelectedValue = null;
}
```

Comment: Read the supplement to my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You specify bindings to the properties of an element (type Category?) of the Categories collection.
But your CombobBox is not bound to the Categories collection, but to the CompositeCollection.
And the first item in this collection is of type ComboBoxItem.
And this type has no properties to which you create bindings.
Notice the "DataContext" column in the binding errors window.
There is a ComboBoxItem type, not a Category type.

To solve this, you can add a new Category element with the necessary values ​​to the CompositeCollection instead of the ComboBoxItem.
But it will be more convenient if you create a static empty instance.
Then, if necessary, it will be possible to compare with it to determine that although it is not null, it is still an empty instance.

```cs
    public class Category
    {
       // Some code

       public static Category Empty {get;} = new Category() {.....};
    }
```

```xml
<ComboBox x:Name="NewNewComboBox"
          SelectedValuePath="CompCategoryId"
          SelectedValue="{Binding CompCategoryId}"
          DisplayMemberPath="CategoryName"
          ItemsSource="{DynamicResource MyCollection}}">
    <ComboBox.Resources>
        <CompositeCollection x:Key="MyCollection">
            <x:Static Member="local:Category.Empty"/>
            <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Categories}"/>
        </CompositeCollection>
    </ComboBox.Resources>
</ComboBox>
```

**P.S.** Additional recommendation.
Although using SelectedValue and SelectedValuePath is possible, in MVVM concept when binding to ViewModel properties, in my opinion it is rather pointless.
Better to use the SelectedItem binding to a ViewModel property of type Category.
According to my personal experience, SelectedValue and SelectedValuePath are mainly used when implementing the solution "inside" the View, without using the ViewModel and MVVM.

> But I cannot edit the FontStyle of it...

To style the elements, you must compare their data context with a null instance.
To do this, you need to create it somewhere, and only then add it to the collection.
If you do this only in XAML, then you need to create a null instance in resources.

```xml
<ComboBox x:Name="NewNewComboBox"
          SelectedValuePath="CompCategoryId"
          SelectedValue="{Binding CompCategoryId}"
          DisplayMemberPath="CategoryName"
          ItemsSource="{DynamicResource MyCollection}}"
          ItemContainerStyle="{DynamicResource itemStyle}">
    <ComboBox.Resources>
        <m:CompCategory x:Key="nullInstance"
                        CategoryName="(clear)"
                        CompCategoryId="0"/>
        <CompositeCollection x:Key="MyCollection">
            <StaticResource ResourceKey="nullInstance"/>
            <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Categories}"/>
        </CompositeCollection>
        <Style x:Key="itemStyle" TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding}"
                             Value="{StaticResource nullInstance}">
                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15"/>
                    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
                    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="arial"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ComboBox.Resources>
</ComboBox>
```

> I would like the solution to avoid code specific to the class the ComboBox uses because I want to make this ComboBox as a UserControl so it can be reused on different class...

I don't think this is a good idea.
The main purpose of a UserControl is to represent the data coming in its DataContext property.
What do you expect the DataContext to receive?
If you want some kind of versatility, then all types entering the DataContext must implement some kind of common interface.
And it is by the implementation of this interface that UserControl will "understand" how to work with this data.
Perhaps Custom Control would be a more better choice for your task.

But for the right advice, you need more details of what you want to implement.

Comment: The "additional recommendation" is plain wrong. You may of course select an item by a "key" property in a view model, hence SelectedValue/SelectedValuePath are totally useful with MVVM.

Comment: Perhaps in some very rare tasks this makes sense.
But at the moment, I cannot think of a single such task where it really makes sense to use SelecteValue, and not SelectedItem.
Perhaps this is because my fantasy is too poor.

Comment: That might be the reason, sure. The properties are there for a reason, even if you personally can't make use of them. You should delete that section from your answer, because it  does really make no sense at all, and may discourage unexperienced programmers from using those properties.

Comment: @EldHasp a style trigger could be added, to accomplish the italic font style, smaller font size and the "(clear)" string as content for the empty catg.

Comment: @lidqy, You're right.
This is the convenience of a static empty instance.
By comparing the value of the current data context to this empty instance, you can change the styling of the ComboBox element.
I didn't show this in the example, because in the code shown by TC, the styling of all elements is the same.

Comment: @Clemens, I am writing in more detail.
Perhaps in rare cases, the use of SelectedValue makes some sense.
But before using it, you need to think about why this property was selected for binding, and not SelectedItem.
And the choice in favor of SelectedValue should be CONSIDERED, and not because you saw it in some example.
If there are no valid arguments in favor of SelectedValue, then it is better to use SelectedItem.

Comment: Better or not is just your personal opinion. Whether you select an item directly, or by one of its properties only depends on the use case and is both equally valid. None is "better" than the other. Even if you never implemented such an approach, it is totally normal to select an item by its unique ID.

Comment: @Clemens, naturally, in the additional recommendation, I write about my personal opinion.
This is not WPF documentation.

Comment: @EldHasp that's perfect thank you.  I'm still trying to learn UserControls and CustomControls.  I managed to make both of them for my code (with the VS xaml binding failures).  I will make another attempt with what you provided.

Comment: Create a new theme with your implementations.
I will try to suggest how best to make them.

Answer (score 0):

The errors are due to absence of the `CompCategoryId` and `CategoryName` in the "Clear" item you had added. Or rather in other words, the newly added item is not of the type which matches the rest of collection and do not have properties which match the DisplayMemberPath and SelectedValuePath.

You could create an object that signifies a [Null Category](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/null_object). For example,

```
public class NullCategory:Category
{
  public NullCategory()
  {
    CompCategoryId = -1;
    CategoryName = "Clear";
  }
}
```

Now you can add your Null Item as the following

```
 <CompositeCollection>
     <ViewModel:NullCategory />
     <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource MyCollection}}"  />
</CompositeCollection>
```